# Different output in codeblocks and visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, codeblocks

Below program  is giving different output in codeblocks and visual studio
for same input

Input: 5 4 1 2 1

**codeblocks**

output: 0.00000000

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double l,d,v,g,r;
    cin>>l>>d>>v>>g>>r;
    if(g*v>d) printf("%.8lf\n",(double)l/v);
    else
    {
        printf("%.8lf\n",ceil(d/v/(g+r)) * (g+r)+(l-d)/v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**visual studio**

output: 7.00000000

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double l, d, v, g, r;
    cin >> l >> d >> v >> g >> r;
    if (g*v > d) printf("%.8lf\n", (double)l / v);
    else
    {
        printf("%.8lf\n", ceil(d / v / (g + r)) * (g + r) + (l - d) / v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is it due to headers or something else

Comment: What compiler does codeblocks use?

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is a bad practice

Comment: when comparing compilers, please *use exactly same code* whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) for details.

Secondly, the output from Visual Studio looks correct to me.

Update your code for CodeBlocks to use the same as the what you have used in Visual Studio and give it another try. Perhaps use of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` has some unwanted side effects.

If that does not resolve your problem, add some diagnostic output to figure out where things could be going wrong. E.g.

```
int main()
{
   double l, d, v, g, r;
   cin >> l >> d >> v >> g >> r;

   printf("l: %f\n", l);
   printf("d: %f\n", d);
   printf("v: %f\n", v);
   printf("g: %f\n", g);
   printf("r: %f\n", r);
   printf("\n");

   printf("(d / v / (g + r)): %f\n", (d / v / (g + r)));
   printf("ceil(d / v / (g + r)): %f\n", ceil(d / v / (g + r)));
   printf("ceil(d / v / (g + r)) * (g + r): %f\n", ceil(d / v / (g + r)) * (g + r));
   printf("(l - d) / v: %f\n", (l - d) / v);
   printf("ceil(d / v / (g + r)) * (g + r) + (l - d) / v): %f\n", ceil(d / v / (g + r)) * (g + r) + (l - d) / v);

   return 0;
}
```

Useful link: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).